# Nested Try and Catch blocks

Tags: c#, web-services, exception

I have nested `try-catch` blocks in a custom C# code for SharePoint. I want to execute the code in only one `catch` block (the inner one) when the code inside the inner `try` block throws an exception.

```
try
{
 //do something

   try
   {
        //do something              if exception is thrown, don't go to parent catch

   }
   catch(Exception ex) {...}

}
catch(Exception ex)
{ .... }
```

I know I can use different types of exceptions but that's not what I am looking for.

**Summary**

If exception occurs, I don't want it to reach the parent `catch` in addition to the inner `catch`.

Comment: They don't normally go to the 'parent'.

Comment: @HenkHolterman In my case they are, I am receiving both exceptions if inner try throws an error :(

Comment: Then the question is missing the most important parts. It's about what you do on the `...` in `catch(Exception ex) {...}`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you don't want to execute the outer exception in that case you should not throw the exception from the inner catch block.

```
try
{
 //do something
   try
   {
      //do something              IF EXCEPTION HAPPENs don't Go to parent catch
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {  
     // logging and don't use "throw" here.
   }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{ 
  // outer logging
}
```

Answer (score 19):

The outer `catch` wouldn't fire if the inner `catch` handled the exception

If you want the outer `catch` to fire as well, you'd have to do:

```
try
{
 //do something

   try
   {
        //do something 

   }
   catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        // do some logging etc...
        throw;
    }

}
catch(Exception ex)
{ 
    // now this will be triggered and you have 
    // the stack trace from the inner exception as well
}
```

Essentially, as you have the code there now, the outer `catch` will not be triggered from the inner `try {} catch {}`

Comment: To the asker's credit, I have the same problem they do. It goes like this: Use .Net PCL/Xamarin on Android. Call an async method with try/catch inside. Have it call another async method, and that has try/catch around a single call. That call fails. The inner try/catch DOES NOT CATCH, even though it's catch(Exception ex). The outer try/catch gets it instead, way too late. I suspect in certain VMs nested try/catch is not actually supported.